# Generating a sum of bernouilli verifying an inequality

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to simulate $N$ random variables $X_1, \cdots, X_N$ with $N>1$ with:

- $X_i \sim \mathbf B {(p)}$ (bernouilli distribution)
- $\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \leqslant K$
- $K$ is an integer strictly below $N$

Any idea on how to simulate this in R or Python?

Thanks for your help on this topic.

Cheers

Comment: You are trying to simulate Bernoulli distributed $X_i$, so you cannot require $\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\leq K<N$.

Comment: Is the second condition mean conditional on $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \leq K$ to have a truncated binomial distribution? There are a naive way: First simulate the sum alone as the truncated binomial. Either calculate the conditional pmf first, or you repeatedly simulate binomial until the condition met. Then you just need to permute the indexes of $X_i$ as you know the number of $1$ is equal to the generated sum.